# When does one negate the return value in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, protractor, jsdoc3

I see this a lot in the Protractor documentation,

```javascript
/**
 * ...
 * ...
 *
 * @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A promise which resolves to the
 *     number of elements matching the locator.
 */
```

What is going on there with the **negation** of the return object? When is it used?

I'll concede that perhaps it is not strictly "negation," but the notation should be documented somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JSDoc spec](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

> **Non-nullable type**
>
> `{!number}`
>   A number, but never null
>
> Indicates that the value is of the specified type, but
>   cannot be `null`.

Comment: Typical, hiding right in front of me in the documentation. Thanks!